# What is best way to copy a C++ structure that contains STL members like vector?

Tags: c++

I know that we can not use memcpy() because it can crash the program.

This is the structure that I want to copy. What is the best way to do this?

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)
typedef struct tagTEST_INFO
{
   char     szCountryCode[100];
   char     szOpFlag[100];
   string   strOrginName;
   vector<RESP_INFO>    vctInfo;
    vector<RESP_HCR_INFO>   vctHcrInfo;

}   TEST_INFO, *P_TEST_INFO;
#pragma pack (pop)
```

Comment: Quick question... Why do you set byte packing when you have non-POD types in there?

Comment: It is just a demo structure and my original structure have members like int, float etc.

Comment: You should demo something that makes sense. Preferably your actual [MCVE].

Comment: What is wrong with the (default) copy constructor?

Comment: I am almost certain, given the attempted `memcpy`, the packing, and the fact that the question needed asking at all.... that the OP wants to serialise this byte-by-byte. OP should be clearer.

Comment: I have seen so many dirt code, that a memcpy, also misused in a constructor, is not related to serializing by default. If OP wants to serailize, he should tell us. If so, take a look at boost::serialize.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing equipped to write the code to perform your copy is the *compiler*. But it needs your help.

If `RESP_INFO` and `RESP_HCR_INFO` are trivially copyable then the compiler will generate adequate copy constructors and assignment operators automatically.

Also drop the C-style `typedef` idiom - it's unnecessary in C++. And is that non-portable packing directive *really* needed? Let the compiler figure out the best way. Moving on, the `std::string` class would probably be a better type for `szCountryCode` and `szOpFlag`.

Comment: Vectors are trivially copyable now?

Comment: Yes that was a bit naughty.

Comment: Why do you need to recast the arrays into `std::string`?  The compiler default copy will handle them fine.

Answer (score 0):

All of your members have assignment operators defined, meaning the built-in assignment operator will copy just fine. It will do a memberwise copy, which in turns calls the assignment operator of the members. You don't need to define your own copy assignment operator.

Comment: OP seems to want to serialise.

Comment: I can't read something about serializing. The question is "best way to copy".